# $\sum_{d\leq x} (\mu(d)/d) \log x/d$: elementary estimates?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let 
$$F(x) = \sum_{d\leq x} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} \log \frac{x}{d}.$$

s it possible/feasible to give an elementary proof of the fact that $F(x)= 1 + o(1)$ (and, ideally, $1+O(1/\log x)$, or better)? By "elementary" I mean "using the properties of $\zeta(s)$ only for $\Re(s)\geq 1$, and of preference only for $s$ real". (Call work with $s$ complex, $\Re(s)\geq 1$, "semi-elementary" if you wish.) I'd also need for it to be possible to make the bounds nicely explicit.

[Note: I am well aware of [Ramaré's](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2015-84-293/S0025-5718-2014-02914-1/) and [Balazard's](http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~balazard/pdfdjvu/22anglais.pdf) work, which relies on estimates on $\sum_{m\leq x} \mu(m)$ (derived in turn from estimates on $\sum_{m\leq x} \Lambda(m)$). I am looking for (semi-)elementary estimates, in part because I would like something that can be easily adapted to analogous sums.]

Comment: In case you (ore other users) will find there something useful (in the answer or in the comments), I'll add a link to math.SE post [Showing that $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log \frac{x}{n} = O(1)$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/68411). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bd%5Cleq%20x%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmu(d)%7D%7Bd%7D%20%5Clog%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bd%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: Probably a very naive question of mine, but would it help in any way to write the considered sum as  $ \sum_{d\leqslant x}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}\log x-\sum_{d\leqslant x}\mu(d)(\log' d.\log d) $?

Comment: according to Sylvain julien , Try to check this Erdos bound , equation 3 and 4 :https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/divisor-function/, in the sense of conditionally convergent series. Assuming one can justify this (which, ultimately, requires one to exclude zeroes of the Riemann zeta function on the line Re(s)=1, you can obtain your estimation

Answer (score 1):

In chapter 4, [p. 15-18](https://books.google.com/books?id=vBe8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA15) of  the book

H. Iwaniec, Lectures on the Riemann Zeta Function, American Mathematical Society, University Lecture Series nº 62, 2014

there is an elementary proof of the prime number theorem with a rest  $\psi(x)=x +O(x(\log x)^{-A})$ with arbitrary A. 
In [page 18](https://books.google.com/books?id=vBe8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18) he propose as exercise to proof
$$ \sum_{m\le x} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\ll (\log  x)^{-A},\qquad
 \sum_{m\le x} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\log m=-1+O((\log x)^{-A}.$$
From this your assertion follows. So it is definitely feasible.

Comment: Er - I'd like to see it done?

Comment: He uses "semi-elementary methods" to prove $M(x)\ll x (\log x)^{-A}$. From this I think there is no much difficulty. Essentially this is done by Landau when he proves  $\sum \mu(n) \log n/n=-1$. (Primzhalen p. 612-613)

Comment: Sure, I agree it's not difficult if you assume that. But what are "semi-elementary methods"? Do you have to work with $\zeta(s)$ to the left of the line $\Re(s)=1$?

Comment: But Iwaniec do not use zeta at Re s=1 only for  $\sigma>1$. Well it is true he uses the behavior near $\sigma=1$ but he appear to prove this in page 10 again without using $\sigma=1$.

Comment: Iwaniec treat the analytic continuation in Chapter 6 of his book.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I wonder whether this proof that $M(x)\ll x (\log x)^{-A}$ can result in reasonable constants. It was my impression that we don't have explicit bounds of such quality for $A>1$.